# Latest poi 5.2.1 version is having issue with HSSFWorkbook(fis)

Tags: apache-poi, xmlbeans, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I have updated poi version from 4.1.1 to 5.2.1. After upgrade I am facing issues with xls and xlsx format files. I currently have poi-5.2.1.jar, poi-ooxml-5.2.1.jar, xmlbeans 3.1.0, commons-io-2.8.0 version and commons-compress-1.21.jar. may I know the compatible versions of xml beans for poi 5.2.1 verison.

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html. Or look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/5.2.1 ->  Compile Dependencies (17).

Comment: HSSFWorkbook doesn't use XMLBeans - XSSFWorkbook does